# Regarding optional path in JAX-RS

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I want to pass an optional parameter in the JAX-RS path.I am using the below path but its not working.

```
@Path("/lock/{userName}/{userid:(([a-zA-Z]{2})?)}")
```

The resource should get invoked for both with userid and without user id parameter in the path.
Can anyone suggest me what needs to be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take out the `/` between the two template parameters and insert it into the regex of the `userId`

```
@Path("/lock/{userName}{userid:((/[a-zA-Z]{2})?)}")
```

Won't make a difference, but the extra wrapping parenthesis are not needed,
 i.e. this `{userid: (/[a-zA-Z]{2})?}` is sufficient

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to use FormParam instead of PathParam

```
@POST
@Path("/lock/{userName}")
public Response resourceName(@PathParam("userName") String userName, @FormParam("userId") String userId)
```

You can provide the userId or not.